# Quotes error in checkbox function call

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5

When I inspect a HTML checkbox element I get this ('SET'):

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="set_str('SET');">
```

but I want this ("SET"):

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="set_str("SET");">
```

In code, I have Laravel value echoed from my controller:

```
 onClick="set_str('{{ $value }}');"
```

If I put double instead of single quotes ('{{ $value }}') , I receive expression expected error.

Comment: Why do you need `"SET"`? `'SET'` is 100% valid.....

Comment: Either `"` or `'` are valid string delimiters in javascript. It should make no difference. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: @epascarello
yes, it's valid

Comment: @Jamiec
Problem is that set_str function is then not called.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the string delimiters you use! Check the console for errors. You have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, not a string delimiter problem.

Comment: @ZeroZek so it is valid...... why do you need something that is impossible to do because of it being invalid?

Comment: Maraboc provided me a solution. I was obviously checking wrong checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
onClick='set_str("{{ $value }}");'
```

Comment: It gives me   onclick="set_stoerliste('SET');"  but I need 
  onclick="set_stoerliste("SET");"

Comment: @ZeroZek That would be invalid html markup, you cant have a double quote inside another double quote. You need to use different string delimiters for the attribute and the javascript inside it